# Clear content of a cell and then set a new value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I´m trying to clear the content of a cell and then set a new value. I know you´ll ask "why not just set a new value instead of clearing the cell first?", but I really need it to be that way. Here´s what I have

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var new = ss.getRange("G1");
new.clearContent();
new.setValue('|');
```

the problem is that the clearing is not happening, I tried a lot of things but none of them worked :S. Does anybody know what I´m doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clear content? That is only the value. What are you trying to clear? Please review the Apps Script documentation on the `Range` class's various `clear...` methods

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `new` as it is [reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). Use something else like `cell`. Also, using `getActiveSheet()` is dangerous because it requires that you actually have that sheet selected. So if you want to modify something in "Sheet1", but your cursor is on a cell in "Sheet2", then you'll get an unexpected result. Instead, clearly specify which sheet you want to use.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");
  var cell = ss.getRange("G1");
  cell.clearContent();
  cell.setValue('|'); 
}
```

To prove that this *does* clear the cell first, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in conjunction with `Utilities.sleep()`. You'll need to use `flush()` because, "[Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)". Calling `flush()` will make sure that all those operations are executed before continuing with the script.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");
  var cell = ss.getRange("G1");
  cell.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000); // You have 10 seconds to check that the cell has cleared
  cell.setValue('|'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried using "cell" but it´s not working either, the value is set but the previous clearing does not happen

Comment: @FabricioNicolásBarbagallo Sorry about that. I think your issues is with `getActiveSheet()`. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks Diego! it´s the weirdest thing but still not working, I´m beggining to think it´s a bug related to googlescript,everything in the code is like it´s supposed to be

Comment: Did you run my function? If that's not working and you're running different code, then you should post the code that you're actually running.

Comment: Yes, I´m running your function. After the cell.clearContent() I put a sleep of 10 seconds and I don´t the cell being cleared on the screen

Comment: @FabricioNicolásBarbagallo [Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) Try doing `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before sleeping.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this worked. I took a different approach, thanks!!